# Symfony 1.4 Form Widget Id generation not woking properly

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have got a problem with the id generation of Symfony Widgets.
(I am new to symfony so I might have made some mistakes.)

At work we used

```
$form->render();
```

to render a form but this gave us not enough control over the table layout.
So I had to break up the rendering process and build the table by hand.
I am now using

```
$Form['<cellname>']->render();
```

for rendering the single widgets.

But with the new rendering i get wrong id's for my widgets.

The form is used to track the share of a single user for the completion of a project per year.

The ids with the old methode were all in the form of

```
project_<CustomIdforDifferentYears>_<UserId>_share
```

but now I get

```
project_year_member_share
```

for all fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony automatically generates the id of your widgets based on few things.

First is the form name which can be specified like below:

```
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('my_form[%s]');
```

Now every widget's id in that form will be prefixed with "my_form".

The rest comes from the widget name. So if the widget name is 'email', your widget's id will be generated as "my_form_email".

If want to specify the widget's id in the template. You can do this also as part of the render method, which accepts an array of options like this:

```
echo $form['email']->render(array('id' => 'my_different_id'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much - i knew how those id's were put together, i just don't understand why I get different id's when i render the whole form or just a single field